# How to exit a loop based on a condition in Power Automate?

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector, power-automate-desktop

I have an excel table and I want to look for a specific value I fetched in it. if it is there then do an action and exit the loop and if not in the list then after exiting the loop do some actions.

[image: 1]

Comment: Hi @omar amr, you might want to look into the do until action. This is an action which can loop until your are meeting a certain criteria. 

Btw, the list rows present in table action also support filtering. You might be able to simplify your flow setup by using that filtering option instead.